# How to return starting and end point of a path in a hierarchical structure

Tags: database, postgresql, recursive-query

I have a table that looks like that

```
---------------------------
| id1 | id2 | col1 | col2 |
+-----+-----+------+------+
|  1  |  1  |  a   |  b   |
|-----+-----+------+------|
|  1  |  2  |  b   |  c   |
|-----+-----+------+------|
|  5  |  1  |  d   |  f   |
---------------------------
```

The idea is that the table stores paths: a->b->c and d->f. What I want is a query that will return a->c and d->f.

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive query:

```
with recursive find_path (col1, col2, depth) as (
    select col1, col2, 1
    from my_table t
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from my_table
        where col2 = t.col1)
union all
    select p.col1, t.col2, depth+ 1
    from my_table t
    join find_path p on p.col2 = t.col1
)

select distinct on (col1) format('%s -> %s', col1, col2) as path
from find_path
order by col1, depth desc;

  path  
--------
 a -> c
 d -> f
(2 rows)
```

---

The question is not quite clear. If your aim is to get the paths in partitions by id1 in order by id2, you can use the window functions:

```
select distinct on (id1)
    id1, first_value(col1) over w, last_value(col2) over w
from my_table
window
    w as (partition by id1 order by id2)
order by id1, id2 desc;

 id1 | first_value | last_value 
-----+-------------+------------
   1 | a           | c
   5 | d           | f
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mean

```
select a, b, c from whateveryourtablenameis;
```

and include whatever columns you want in addition to a, b, and c.

This would return just columns a, b, and c. I know of no way to ask SQL for a range of columns other than *.